# c++ threadpool with shared read only memory

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I am a newbie in concurrent programming in C++
I want to code a server( on a linux box ) based on the thread pool pattern where
threads need to read ( and only read ) from a shared memory
to answer incoming requests

I am very confused :(
I wonder if something needs to be done to synchronize threads 
when they access the read only memory and how to do it ( using memory map file maybe ? )

Comment: pthreads...http://www.cs.nmsu.edu/~jcook/Tools/pthreads/library.html...to sync the threads you can use the join method to access shared memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data is read-only then you don't need to synchronize the reading threads, you only do that if something is writing. Also, threads share their parent's memory space so you don't need to make a shared memory segment or anything like that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety

Answer (score 1):

I know very good article about C++11 multithreading - [Read it](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-1-starting-threads.html). In the part 4 you will see shared container implementation and explanation.